# Why is my JS not working despite the coding being correct?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
// JavaScript Document
"use strict";
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scroll() > 100){
  $("#scrollTop").fadeIn();
  }
 });

$(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(window).scroll() < 100){
  $("#scrollTop").fadeOut();
  }
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fa').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1000);
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
#scrollTop{
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 20px;
 right: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
  background-color:#0D0155;
}

#scrollTop:after{
 font-family: fontAwesome;
 content:"\f102";
}

.fa {
 padding: 20px;
 width: 60px;
   font-size: 15px!important;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 5px 2px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-delay:0.3s;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(20deg,#0D0155,#3A83F3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(20deg,#0D0155,#3A83F3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(20deg,#0D0155,#3A83F3);
  color: white;
 margin-left: 10px;
 
}

.fa:hover {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0D0155, #0D0155);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #0D0155, #0D0155);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0D0155, #0D0155);
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="fa" id="scrollTop"></div>
```

```js
"use strict"
$(window).scroll(function(){
"use strict";
if($(window).scrollTop() > 300){
    $('#scrollTop').fadeIn();
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
"use strict";
if($(window).scrollTop() < 300){
    $('#scrollTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
$('#scrollTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1000);
    return false;
 });
});
```

Right, I'm attempting to implement a button which fades in at the bottom of the screen once the user scrolls a certain distance from the top.

This button must scroll to the top of the webpage once clicked.

This worked before and now it's just decided to stop working. This is not acaptable.

I have tried the following:

- I have tried the "use strict" function at the top of the document.
- I have tried the "use strict" function into each of the ode functions themselves.
- I have removed the "use strict" function into each of the code functions themselves.
- I have removed the "use strict" function at the top of the document.
- I have tried switching from double quotes to single quotes.
- I have tried switching from single quotes back to double quotes.
- I have tried inserting the JS into the webpage itself as supposed to a link in the head section to the JS Document.
- I have removed the JS into the webpage itself as supposed to a link in the head section to the JS Document.
- I have removed the "type:text.javascript" from the link in the head.
- I have inserted the "type:text.javascript" from the link in the head.
- I have tried inserting into the JS code the ".fa" class.
- I have tried this with the "scrollTop" ID attribute.

The expected results were for JS to do something amazing and just do what the code tells it do to, the action results were not so surprising in that nothing happened. No faded in button, and nothing happens when you click this.

Quite frankly I've just about had enough of coding deciding it's not going to work when this has worked perfectly fine before.

So why isn't thing doing as it's told?

Comment: It looks like you need to put the JavaScript inside the script tag.

Comment: maybe you should have an ide ? that would show that the code is not code but TEXT  and also you only need one "use strict"

Comment: You should only define one `onScroll` function on window, otherwise the second one just overwrites the first one

Comment: @evolutionxbox You can't have a `<script>` tag with an `src` *and* inline content. And @Asthmatic, it actually won't overwrite, it will just add another event (scrolling would now fire two events instead of just one). That said, having two of the same handler on the same element is a very bad idea, *especially* when it comes to something as intensive as window scrolling.

Comment: @TylerRoper that’s me not looking properly again.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No worries :)  OP, the code you've posted simply *isn't code*. Putting text on an HTML page without wrapping it in any sort of indicator will appear as just text. If you preview your page and see your javascript appearing as plaintext on the screen, that's a red flag that something is very obviously wrong.

Comment: @TylerRoper jquery strikes again

Comment: I'm just going to start screaming in a minute, this has worked perfectly before. Now it's just stopped. what is the correct syntax then because clearly Dreamweaver has randomly decided it doesn't like what it's getting....

Comment: @user8709679 You have a big block of javascript, simply wrap it in `<script> ... </script>`. There are some other "smells" in your code but that would be the primary reason that it isn't executing at all.

Comment: Thats fine, what smells would these be? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6cpf07ed/

Your code is fine except you need to call `scrollTop()` jQuery function instead of `scroll()`

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
        $("#scrollTop").fadeIn();
        }
    });

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() < 100){
        $("#scrollTop").fadeOut();
        }
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```